# How can I give docker containers access to postgresql running on the host?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have postgresql running on the host, and I'd now like to connect to it from the docker containers also running on the host.

Within my docker-compose.yaml I have

```
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Set on the container, and within the container I'm able to ping host.docker.internal successfully, however when connecting to `host.docker.internal:5432` the port that postgres is running on, it is refused. Likely beacuese postgres is configured to only listen on 127.0.0.1:5432.

**How can I configure postgres to allow connections as the above?** I'm not quite sure how docker configures the networks, for example if I modify postgres to allow a subnet that is configured with docker, I'm not sure if docker will change this network subnet at some point (for example if I recreate the docker-compose containers).

I do not want to fully open it under something like allowing `0.0.0.0`.

---

Looking at the tshark output when I attempt to connect I see:

```
95 26.891536270 192.168.32.2 → 172.17.0.1   TCP 76 46440 → 5432 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2274078019 TSecr=0 WS=128
96 26.891557842 192.168.32.2 → 172.17.0.1   TCP 76 [TCP Out-Of-Order] [TCP Port numbers reused] 46440 → 5432 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2274078019 TSecr=0 WS=128
97 26.891577870   172.17.0.1 → 192.168.32.2 TCP 56 5432 → 46440 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
98 26.891581727   172.17.0.1 → 192.168.32.2 TCP 56 5432 → 46440 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

So `192.168.32.2` which seems to be under another bridge network that docker configures automatically.

Comment: You'll need to alter your [`listen_addresses`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html).

Comment: Yup, the question is to what though?

Comment: Either `0.0.0.0` or `::1`, though be advised that this exposes it to *any* machines on your local network. You may want to run Postgres in a container as well, then use `compose` to link this to other containers.

Comment: That is a workaround, but I'd like to configure it exactly as it is now (running on host) and only allowing localhost OR connections from the docker containers.

Comment: You can always poke around with `ifconfig` or `ip addr` to find out which address(es) you want to bind to, then list those specifically.

Comment: Sure that would work in this specific case, but the thing is those IPs will change. I need to be able to copy this docker-compose config and spin up a new set of containers, while allowing them access to 
postgresql.

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting running Postgres in a container, too, then Docker knows exactly what's going on and can configure your networking for you accordingly. Postgres isn't Docker aware, but Docker is aware of what port(s) Postgres uses, and what IP the container spun up with.

Comment: I do not want to go with that suggested approach even though I understand that it would work.

Comment: Well, good luck with that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the container to use the default `bridge` network:

```
services:
  api: 
    network_mode: bridge
```

Get the default `bridge` network gateway and subnet:

```
gateway=$(sudo docker network inspect bridge | jq -r '.[] .IPAM.Config[].Gateway')
subnet=$(sudo docker network inspect bridge | jq -r '.[] .IPAM.Config[].Subnet')
```

---

In `postgresql.conf` change the listen address to include the docker bridge gateway:

```
# change this
# listen_addresses = 'localhost'               # what IP address(es) to listen on;
# to:
listen_addresses = 'localhost,172.17.0.1'               # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Add the subnet to `pg_hba.conf`:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'host    all             all             ${subnet}            trustscram-sha-256' >> /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf"
```